# How can I block direct IP access to my web server without response error code?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I hope people can help me with this question.

Example:

My domain name is: example.com

My IP Address is 103.103.103.103

When people try to connect to my IP on port 80. It will not respond any request.

It should show: connecting(on browser)... with no response.(It will look like unable to connect)

I have tried to modify httpd.conf(i'm using apache 2.4) but not successful yet.

I tried googling but there is no result for my question.

Thank you

Comment: All the communication is done by IP addresses.  A connection would have to be established for the web server to know what address was used in the browser.  You can't do what you're trying to.

Comment: With Apache???? Nginx you can `return 444;`

Comment: A firewall will do that, but the purpose of a web server is to answer requests. Why would you configure a web server to not respond to any requests?

Comment: Just shut down your web server. Then it will no longer respond.

Comment: LOL! Sorry for this stupid question when I got the answers LMAO. I have idea to protect my server by a small ddos stress test. I’m using cloudflare to hide my ip. I just want to anti ddos with this idea. But look like it is not available to do lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want requests to http://example.com to serve your website, and requests to http://103.103.103.103 to be explicitly dropped you have 2 main options that I am aware of.

1) is to use [mod_security](http://www.modsecurity.org/#N11041) module and the `drop` target. A configuration like this;

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName default.only
        SecRuleEngine On
        SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^\d" id:'1234',drop,phase:1
    </VirtualHost>

    <Directory /var/www/example.com >
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride FileInfo Options
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

returns the website, if you go to http://example.com

```
# wget -O-  http://example.com
--2018-03-09 15:35:35--  http://example.com/
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’
```

and if you try to go to the default site via ip http://127.0.0.1

```
# wget -O-  http://127.0.0.1
--2018-03-09 15:35:28--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
```

The connection is dropped

2) The second option is to use the `string` module for **iptables** and drop connections with a header matching `Host: 103.103.103.103`

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "Host: 103.103.103.103" -j DROP
```

(I didn't test that iptables rules...so you would have to check the docs for the correct incantation...)
However I think the mod_security option is simpler